# Symfony writeln have no color in Laravel php artisan serve

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

I want to print something by `php artisan serve`

In my controller action, I add some code like this:

```php
public function show($id) {
    ...
    $output = new \Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput();
    $output->writeln("<info>Hello World!</info>");
}
```

`Hello World!` is printed on `php artisan serve` without color.

If I put these two lines [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ServeCommand.php#L38). `Hello World!` is printed and it is green.

So how to print the sentence **with color** on `php artisan serve` in **controller action**.

Comment: Did you try to use [OutputStyle](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Console/OutputStyle.php) instead of Symfony Console Output? like used in https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ServeCommand.php#L38

Comment: @qdequippe `outputStyle` has no print method, I try to use [Command](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php) with `OutputStyle`, but it still print msg without color.